# solo.clickOnButton() not working properly

Tags: android, listview, button, robotium

I am trying to use solo.clickOnButton() in a loop, but the button is clicked only for the first time. After that, it doesn't click at all. The scenario is like this: I have a listView and when I click each item in list, an activity is opened and that activity has a button. I am trying to click that button everytime. 
Here's my code:

```
for(int i=0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
            solo.clickOnView(getViewAtIndex(list, i, getInstrumentation()));

            solo.assertCurrentActivity("DetailsActivity not found", "DetailsActivity");
            Button fullDetails = (Button) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.btn);
                solo.sleep(2000);
                //solo.waitForView(fullDetails, 4000, true);
                solo.clickOnView(fullDetails);
                    solo.goBack();
                  }
```

Please help...

Comment: I tried using solo.clickOnButton(name) also with no success..

Comment: What error do you get? can you post a logcat?

Comment: Actually, it passes the test case..but it doesn't click the button after first time.. Button not clicked is evident as it doesn't go to next screen on button click..which it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(com.example.test.R.id.your_view));
```

if the problem still exists I suggest you to ask the robotium people [here](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/list)

good luck

Comment: Indeed that worked better. `onButtonClick` uses `clickOnScreen(waiter.waitForAndGetView(index, viewClass))` which does much more then a simple click and is therefore more failure prone.